# msvcr100d.dll and msvcp100d.dll missing from debug execution path

Tags: c#, c++, .net

I've got a mixed Visual C++ and C# solution, and whenever I try and run it in debug mode, the program fails because the C++ project is attempting to load `msvcp100d.dll` and `msvcr100d.dll`. The same happens if I try and run the unit tests.

This doesn't happen in Release mode though. Does anyone know if I can remove the dependency on this library in debug mode?

Comment: Does your VC++ code use a `/clr` variant or is it purely native?

Comment: Don't the dlls get shipped with VS? The debug dlls aren't redistributable (at least they're not meant to be redistributed)

Comment: The debug dlls are on my machine, but for some reason Visual Studio doesn't seem to be able to find them. Maybe this is because the entry point is a C# app, and so it isn't looking in the additional locations for C++ dlls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know if I can remove the dependency on this library in debug mode?

Yes, in your project's properties, configure it to link to the non-debug version of the C runtime library. You want the `/MD` switch (rather than `/MDd`, which indicates the debug version). However, note that by doing this, you will lose the debugging features of the CRT.

The better solution is to figure out how your development environment got borked. The DLLs should be available whenever Visual Studio is installed.

Comment: Note that if he compiles with any `/clr` variant then `/MT` will not be an option.

Comment: True enough, and dynamic linking to the CRT is a better option anyway.

Comment: @ildjarn unfortunately, I am indeed compiling with `/clr`. What path variable do I need to modify to make this library available?

Comment: @Ceilingfish : Your __only__ option when compiling with `/clr` is to compile with `/MD` instead of `/MDd`.

Comment: Hi, I tried switching that configuration variable, and it still appears to be trying to load those dlls. I changed the option under `Configuration Properties` => `C/C++` => `Code Generation`. Is there anywhere else it needs changing?

Comment: Make sure that you've changed it for the active configuration and rebuilt your project.

Comment: yep, I changed it for `Debug` and `Release`. Debug is the active configuration.